# Show notification Alarm Manager / Wake Lock / Sleep (local notification in Android)

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, wakelock, standby

I want to display a notification / alarm with the terminal in "sleep mode / standby". As does WhatsApp, Handcensms ... Or the simple alarm clock.

For example, in IOS is called "local notification" and looks like:
http://www.remotenotification.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/PushNotification1.jpg

I'm reading about AlarmManager, WindowManager .. But I fail to understand.

Can anyone help me or guide me?

I do not know what uses-permission are necessary.

regards & thanks

Comment: In android this is called a Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a rather stupid response but do you mean toast messages? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

```
Toast.makeText(context, "This text will be displayed", 100).show();
```

Comment: Maybe this will be any help http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification